# How can I make sticky navbar to work across other components?

Tags: html, angular, components, navbar, sticky

I have following structure in Project :

```
    <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
    <app-slider></app-slider>
    <app-solution></app-solution>
    <app-platform></app-platform>
    <app-team></app-team>
    <app-contact></app-contact>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

Sticky nav-bar is not working because it only works inside its component how can I make it to work for components and stay on top.

I tried puting it in app.component.html but it doesnt work.